# Perform addition on bit-fields in C#

Tags: c#, enums, bit-fields

I am working on a Gomoku implementation in C#, and the first challenge of the project is to intelligently represent the state of the board.

In order to achieve this goal, I decided to turn to bit-fields to represent the value of a combination:

```
[Flags]        
public enum CombinationValue : byte   
{
    OnePawn = 1,
    TwoPawns = 2,
    ThreePawn = 4,
    FourPawn = 8,
    FivePawns = 16
}
```

The problem that I stumbled on, is that when I want to increment a combination, I want to unset the previous bit and set a new one, which is basically a binary shift to the left, which is not allowed with enum.
For example, let's say I have a combination of two pawns, and a pawn is put next to it so the value of the enum must become "ThreePawn" instead of "TwoPawns".

So basically, what I want to do is TwoPawns + OnePawn == ThreePawns.

What would be the most efficient way to implement this behavior?

Comment: You can cast the enum to an integer then perform any math you want.

Comment: If `ThreePawn` would be `3` instead of `4`, wouldn't all work as you'd expect? Also, if you want to bit-shift, cast to the underlying type, in this case `byte`.

Comment: so `TwoPawns + ThreePawn = FivePawns` ? I don't see how you can get 16 or even 8 from 2 + 6

Comment: Why not just use a number? Why do you have to mix in enums at all? `int numberOfPawns = 0;` What am I missing here?

Comment: Consider using a number base struct or class with overloaded operators +,- == and !=. I guess it will be much more readable and powerful, because you can do more operations, For example, you can implement IEquatable, IComparabale, override ToString(), add you own methods ans so on.  It's not possible to perfom in with way with enums/flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how flags should be used. Flags are used to designate **switches** in a single byte, so given the binary `0000` the first bit represents an element being "on", the second a different element, etc.

So element1 is represented by: `1 = 0001`, Element2: `2= 0010`, Element3: `4 = 0100`, etc. So to turn element 1 and element 2 on you use the binary `0011` or `3` (`1+2`).

FYI; this dates back to the days when computers had limited memory and being able to represent multiple states in a small number of bits was advantagous.

What you want doesn't make sense from a binary point of view, three prawns would be `0011` or switch 1 and 2. This isn't really a "state". which is what switches are for.

If you want to designate the number of prawns and perfrom addition, what's wrong with a good old fashined `int`?

Comment: I had the intuition that my used of bit-fields was unappropriate. With your answer it is very clear that an integer would be much better. Thanks !

Comment: @Anonymouss the best way to say thanks is to mark as answer and/or upvote as you deem appropriate

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then you can just do this:

```
CombinationValue result = CombinationValue.OnePawn | CombinationValue.TwoPawns;
```

But you will need to have ThreePawn as 3 then.